# Visa requirements for travelling from the US to Sri Lanka through Dublin, Ireland

Tags: usa, transit-visas, ireland, sri-lankan-citizens, dub

My daughter has a Sri Lankan passport and is a university student in the USA. She has a valid US visa and she has already purchased a return ticket to come home to Sri Lanka and return to the USA to continue her studies. However, that ticket includes a transfer through Dublin, Ireland, with a 1 hour layover.

Will she require a transit visa?

Comment: According to [INIS](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Transit%20visas), your daughter _will_ need a transit visa.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - Ireland requires that certain countries obtain a transit visa, even if just to pass through an airport. Your daughter will have to apply and pay the 25 Euro transit fee online.

Source:

> http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Transit%20visas